# Can I estimate the row count of a large mysql table using the disk space?

Tags: mysql

Sysadmin here (not a developer by trade), so go easy please ;)

I have a mysql table, on a linux server that uses `innodb_file_per_table`.

When I try to do `select count(foo) from table;` It doesn't finish.  I gave it a good 5 minutes before interrupting.

The `table.ibd` file is about 43G (45176848384).  Since the count() seemed like it was never going to finish, I decided to try the following to get an estimate of the row count:

I dumped the first 10,000 rows of the table and imported it to a local database that also has `innodb_file_per_table` and I hope all else equal.

That file, after I imported it, (with only 10,000 rows) is about 2M (2097152)

So:

```
45176848384/2097152
21542
21542*10000
215420000
```

Then, is it correct to assume that the ~43G table is around 215 million rows?  Are there other considerations I'm overlooking?

Or is there a better way for me to determine how many rows are in this table?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120075/mysql-get-the-number-of-rows-in-an-innodb-table

Comment: @JoshuaMartell That's perfect for me.  So I was way off.  It's ~500 million rows.  Thanks.  This can be marked as a duplicate I suppose

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make that kind of approximation work if the InnoDB table experiences DELETE and UPDATEs. With [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled and a table called `mydb.mytable`, this is what you get

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytables.frm` : Table Format Info
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytables.ibd` : This file contains data pages and index pages making up the table and its indexes ([Each page is 16KB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size)).

  - There will be fragmentation amongst the data pages due to DELETEs and UPDATEs
  - There will be fragmentation amongst the index pages due to BTREE operations (node balancing, node splits, etc).

Even if you defragment the InnoDB with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, there is no way of knowing if a single row occupies two or more pages.

## ALTERNATIVE APPROACH

You could probably force the index statistics to give you a round figure. You could just run

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.mytable;
```

Look at the Cardinality column of the `PRIMARY KEY`. That will give you a very close guess at the rowcount. However, if you run `SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.mytable;` multiple times on a large table, you get a different number each time. That's because InnoDB will scan the BTREE nodes and give a roundabout number. If you want to go by the Cardinality of the PRIMARY KEY as the rowcount, you should run this

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0;
```

before running `SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.mytable;`

Believe me, this is a much better guess that dumping a subset of the data and guessing from the filesize.